# Why this event is fired?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I have a page with a repeater and a button. (quite simple)

My repeater have an event `rptEtats_ItemCreated` raised `OnItemCreated`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptEtats" runat="server" OnItemCreated="rptEtats_ItemCreated">
    <ItemTemplate>

    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public void rptEtats_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    //Stuff
}
```

The button on the page raise a OnClick event

```
<asp:Button ID="btnValid" runat="server" Text="Valid" OnClick="btnValid_click" />
```

CodeBehind:

```
public void btnValid_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Stuff
}
```

It's work fine until I click on the button, I expect the `btnValid_click` method but the `rptEtats_ItemCreated` method is called first! I don't understand why. Is the page load again before call the button method? Why the repeater is databinding again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cal `rptEtats.Databind();` at Page_Init, that is before view state is loaded. In that case controls would be re-created properly and button onclik would be fired.

Answer (score 2):

The repeater is not bound again. It stores a count of items in the view state. On post-back it reads this value and creates its child controls (items) the appropriate number of times in order for them to be able to load their own view state. The `ItemCreated` event is fired every time an item is created.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you have in the Page_Load event, a `rptEtats.Databind()` call.

Am I right ?

If true, sorround the call this method like this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        rptEtats.Databind();
    }

}
```

The behavior you notice is due of the page lifecycle. The Page Load event is called before the Click events.

Comment: Oups, I confused with the Item_Databound. Sorry